# How to convert array in php to comma seperated string?

Tags: php, arrays

On using this in PHP

```
$datay1 = array_values($dataArray);
```

I get the output in the below form

```
Array ( [0] => 19 [1] => 17 [2] => 2 [3] => 18 [4] => 53 )
```

I want it to be converted to ("19,17,2,18,53"), taking in only the values and pass it to a function.

Comment: use `implode()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
echo implode(',', $datay1);
```

Comment: you are the first answered .

Comment: yeah thanks, all looks like given different answer rather than upvote same answer

Comment: @RakeshSharma Well... Mine was 2 seconds after... it takes some time to type in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the php function implode:

```
implode(',',$datay1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

echo implode(',', $datay1);